# callback function gives an error - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, function, callback

I am using the $timeout service in angular to decrease a variable from 100 down to 1 every 1/10 seconds.

I know there is a much easier way to do this using the $interval service and I've done it. But, here, specifically, I am testing a callback in angular - not really trying to decrease a variable from 100 down to 1 every 1/10 seconds.

**Specifically, I want the callback to be called when the $timeout function is sleeping (for 1/10 seconds)**

My question is why I get an "undefined is not a function" error when using a callback. I have included the JS code below. It's also on JSbin [here](http://jsbin.com/fiqeq/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Here's the JS code:

```
 var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

 testApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {


  var q = 100;

  function decreaseQ(callback) {
    $scope.someThing = q;


    if(q>0){ $timeout(decreaseQ, 100);q--;}

   callback();

  }

  decreaseQ(function(){console.log("Hello World");});

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because after the first invocation of `decreaseQ` with a function argument you are calling `decreaseQ` without any argument by setting it in the timeout.But you expect a callback and you invoke the function `decreaseQ()` which causes the error.

Instead you would just need to pass the function as callback.

```
  if (q-- > 0) {
     $timeout(function() {
       decreaseQ(callback); //Pass the callback as argument
     }, 100);
   }
```

Or use bound function

```
 $timeout(angular.bind(null, decreaseQ, callback), 100);
```

or just do not run if there is no callback provided by adding a check.

```
 if(angular.isFunction(callback)) { callback(); }
```

Or use the dummy anonymous function

```
(callback||angular.noop)();
```